# Unable to record using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record a http web page using Jmeter 2.3.3 version.I has setup the JMeter proxy and tried, but did n't work. I have followed the below steps.

1. Launch jmeter 2.3.3, added thred group to test plan
2. Under Workbench->add->non-test elements-> added HTTP proxy server.
   proxy server setting are port:9090, target:use recording controller, grouping:donot group samplers, Type:HTTp request and checked the boxes of all under http sampler settings
3. Saved the settings
4. Now in browser(IE 7.0 or firefox 3.0.16), under connection settings, setup the manual proxy settings as local host and port as 9090(no auto detect settings nothing, only manual proxy). Setting saved
5. Now in the jmeter, started the http proxy server.
6. Open a browser and hit the webpage needs to be tested.

The page is not opened. In fact because of the changes made in browsers, no pages are opened. Whenever i try hitting a page, the pages are recorded in the Jmeter. but without the page open, how can i test.

I looking for an immediate answer and my work is blocked. Immediate answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the port and try, mine worked with a different port

Answer (score 0):

when u set the proxy server then it ll work for jmeter only.for getting the page u must unchecked the proxy server settings.
8080 port ,try with ip localhost.it ll work